# Are these the correct steps to implement secure PHP user login?

Tags: php, security, session

I need to do straightforward but secure (not Fort Knox, but sensible) logins to my PHP site. I'm thinking the steps for this are:

1. Users access site via HTTPS
2. Username and password entered on login screen, hashed on the server and compared with pre-hashed password (from when they registered), stored in the database in the user's record. I'm intending to use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) for doing the hashing (which uses salts)
3. All database queries use parameter binding to protect against SQL injection
4. When the user is logged in, I set `$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true` and use `session_regenerate_id`
5. I set `session.use_only_cookies` option

Anything I'm missing here?

Also, I'm not sure best methods to protect against CSRF, XSS attacks, any suggestions?

If it's relevant I'm hosting on Google App Engine, and using their NoSQL Cloud Datastore as my database and using the PHP-GDS lib (https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds) as my DB interface.

Comment: If you just want to implement authentication, use an existing package from Symfony or Zend. It'll save you a lot of hassle.

Comment: Thanks, which packages are you thinking of exactly? I'm unfamiliar with either of those.

Answer (score 2):

If you'll echo any user input data, you need to escape it using PHP's  [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function, to prevent XSS attacks.

```
$foo = '<script>alert("This is bad!")</script>';

// produces a browser alert!
echo $foo;

// just write down the "<script>alert("This is bad!")</script>" string,
// because it converts "<" to "&lt;" and so on...
echo htmlspecialchars( $foo );
```